# How to share the same reference counter in shared pointers of unrelated types?

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr, reference-counting

I have one class member of another. I want to convert a shared pointer to master class to that of member. I.e both objects have shared lifetime and the last one to go out of scope will destroy both of them correctly.

```
#include<memory>
struct Mem
{
};
struct Cont
{
  Mem m;
};
```

I tried the following which works but not perfect. Especially `mptr.unique()` will not be correct. Is there a better way to correctly share the reference counters?

```
void foo()
{
  std::shared_ptr<Cont> contPtr = std::make_shared<Cont>();  
  std::shared_ptr<Mem> mptr(&contPtr->m, [contPtr](Mem*){});

}
```

Comment: Fix your design instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
std::shared_ptr<Cont> contPtr = std::make_shared<Cont>();  
std::shared_ptr<Mem> mptr(contPtr, &contPtr->m);
```

It's (8) on [this list of `std::shared_ptr`'s constructors](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/shared_ptr)